# How to manage multiple threads

Tags: c#

I have software that loads a list of up to 10,000 URLs which are used to scrape insurance prices for my website.

I have a single thread running at the moment per request which loads each URL from the list and fetches the data. What I want to do is run 20-30 requests per time. What's the best way to  launch 20-30 threads at once whilst looping through the results from the textfile?

Comment: You could load the entire list at one go and hand off a chunk from it (say 50 URLs) to each new thread that you spawn, till you reach the max thread count (say 20 threads). Tweak the numbers as necessary.

Comment: I would probably scale back your ambitions, with that number of outbound request any website will rack up the bandwidth charges at an astronomical rate.

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853907/limit-the-number-of-parallel-threads-in-c-sharp/8853978#8853978

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Task Parallel Library and especially the [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET 4 then you can take a look at [TPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Parallel_Library#Task_Parallel_Library) and something like the following.

```
const string path = @"c:\urls.txt";
string[] urls = File.ReadAllLines(path);            

var options = new ParallelOptions() 
              { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20};

Parallel.ForEach(urls, options, url =>
            {
                // Call your scraper here
                Debug.WriteLine(url);
            });
```