# How to configure a maximum number of threads in a Parallel.For

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing

This is the example microsoft presents for the parallel for, and I'd like to know how configure a maximum number of threads for this code.

```
     // A basic matrix multiplication.
     // Parallelize the outer loop to partition the source array by rows.
     System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, matARows, i =>
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < matBCols; j++)
        {
           // Use a temporary to improve parallel performance.
           double temp = 0;
           for (int k = 0; k < matACols; k++)
           {
              temp += matA[i, k] * matB[k, j];
           }
           result[i, j] = temp;
        }
     }); // Parallel.For
```

Comment: Is that *really* the example presented? Because it's really invalid at the moment. Could you show where that's presented?

Comment: Yeah. Well, here I only presented the relevant fragment. The whole example is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx

Comment: You presented a fragment which is syntactically incorrect, by sticking "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions" in the middle of the argument list for no reason.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I was blind to what you were saying. Fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit the number of parallel threads in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853907/limit-the-number-of-parallel-threads-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to specify a [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) value with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`:

For example:

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, count =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(count);
});
```

Comment: for Parallel for each use : Parallel.ForEach(lines,new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, line =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
});

Answer (score 4):

Use [MaxDegreeOfParalelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property for running the loop

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you take a look at the [ParallelOption.MaxDegreesofParellelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) and pass it into the `For` method