# how do I add to a parallel list in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, ftp, parallel-processing, asp.net-4.5

I was reading this post [Limit the number of parallel threads in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853907/limit-the-number-of-parallel-threads-in-c-sharp) and trying to use it to send multiple files via ftp at the same time:

```
Perhaps something along the lines of:

    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();

    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
    Then in your loop something like:

    Parallel.Invoke(options,
     () => new WebClient().Upload("http://www.linqpad.net", "lp.html"),
     () => new WebClient().Upload("http://www.jaoo.dk", "jaoo.html"));
```

I am trying to add the files in my directory to the Invoke but I wasn't sure how to add them:

```
  var dirlisting = Directory.GetFiles(zipdir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
  if (!dirlisting.Any())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error! No zipped files found!!");
    return;
  }

  foreach (var s in dirlisting)
  {
    var thread = new Thread(() => FtpFile.SendFile(s));
    thread.Start();
  }
```

I wasn't sure how to add them to the list of files to send. I only want 3 to go up at a time.

How do I add a thread for each file in the directory listing to be sent?

Comment: `dirlisting.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(3).ForAll(FtpFile.SendFile)` , C# is pretty amazing at this sort of thing, you shouldn't worry about threads, although - I'd recommend looking into asynchronous I/O if you want to do it efficiently, namely - with the newer `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do the trick

```
ParallelOptions o = new ParallelOptions();
o.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;

Parallel.ForEach(dirlisting, o, (f) => 
{
   Ftp.SendFile(f);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.For` family of APIs is for CPU-bound tasks. You have IO-bound tasks here. Ideally, you should be using some asynchronous I/O `Task`-based API.

`HttpClient` doesn't support FTP uploads, but you can use `FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync` and `Stream.WriteAsync`. You can use `WebClient.UploadFileAsync` too, but you'd need to create a new `WebClient` instance per each `UploadFileAsync`, as `WebClient` doesn't support multiple operation in parallel on the same instance.

Then you can use TPL Dataflow Library or just `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the level of parallelism. For examples, check ["Throttling asynchronous tasks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492383/throttling-asynchronous-tasks).

Answer (score 0):

These lines Worked for me.

```
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 };
Parallel.ForEach(dirlisting, options, (item) =>
{
   FtpFile.SendFile(item)
});
```